# What do you call a brightly lit spot?

Tags: word-choice

What do you call a brightly lit spot, especially as a result of reflecting the light source (e.g. sun) off a glassy surface?

Comment: It is a [specular highlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_highlight)

Comment: @StoneyB That's an answer.

Comment: @StoneyB that's *the* answer. You should post it.

Comment: @StoneyB It's not too late to re-post your comment as an answer. It may be concise, but it perfectly describes the phenomenon that the asker mentioned, and I would hate for your answer to be lost (as it is, after all, posted as a comment).

Comment: It's only a specular highlight if you're talking about the bright spot *on* the reflective surface. If you mean the spot of light on *another* surface that results from reflection (like a mirror onto the ceiling), it's called a specular *reflection*. The question seems ambiguous to me.

Comment: Someone who's into physics would have answered this in twenty seconds flat. I found this http://zonalandeducation.com/mstm/physics/light/rayOptics/reflection/reflection1.html about reflective rays and there's ole' Wikipedia which talks about [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28physics%29).

Answer (score 4):

I believe that would be [glare](http://i.word.com/idictionary/glare).

> **glare** (*noun*): a harsh uncomfortably bright light (the glare of a neon sign) (the glare of publicity); especially: painfully bright sunlight

Answer (score 0):

*sparkle*, *gleam*, *flash*.

["It will flame out, like shining from shook foil..." -- GMH]

Answer (score -1):

*...especially as a result of **reflecting** the light source (e.g. sun) off a **glassy surface**?*

> **[Catoptric](http://english_contemporary.enacademic.com/31096/catoptric)** adj. pertaining to the branch of optics which studies **reflected light from mirrors and shiny surfaces**

.

> **[Relucent](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/cide/147026/Relucent)**:  **Reflecting light**; shining; glittering; glistening; bright; luminous; splendid. [1913 Webster]